# Return 1 if command output is empty without capturing it

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have a shell script which ends with a few pipes `grep ... | while read ...| sort | uniq` and I want to return 1 if the output is empty, but uniq always returns 0 even if its input is empty.

So far the best solution I've found is adding grep with an empty pattern `... uniq | grep ''`, this works perfectly but feels more like a hack.

So my question is:  Is there any better/canonical way to do this?

Some restrictions:

- I don't want to capture my output in a variable since I would need to print it again afterwards: `a=$(... | uniq); printf '%s\n' "$a"; [ -n "$a" ]` which doesn't feel right either.
- If possible I'd also prefer a standard tool (no moreutils) and something portable

Thanks!

Comment: Storing it and printing it is unavoidable, even if you use a program like `tee`. While some programs make it look like it does not store it and print it later, that is what you have to do to check the output of a command and then running it

Comment: In these cases I tend to use `wc -l` and check the output but this is not better than your approach.

Comment: yeah store and print later is indeed probably what uniq and sort are doing, but the less I do it the better

Comment: What about a function like: `muniq () { uniq | grep . ;}`?

Comment: @Jesse_b yes it's easier to read but it's still a hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I think `| grep ''` is just fine. You've already used a bunch of programs in the pipeline, so forking out another one isn't going to hurt. And you already know what `grep` does, so there's no debugging with regard to writing some "smart" shell snippet to do it.

The comments mentioned also `| grep .`, which might be another possibility. `grep .` doesn't match on an empty line, `grep ''` does, so choose depending on which one you want.

Though, using `grep` like that might not be immediately obvious to a casual reader, so you might want to add a comment about its purpose in any case.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll stick with this, too bad there's nothing more obvious than grep.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the work:

```
[ -n "$(command | tee /dev/tty)" ]
```

`tee` will send `command`'s output to both stdout (where it's evaluated by the `test` command) and your terminal (`/dev/tty`), so you can see the output without capturing it in a variable.

It's a POSIX-compliant solution AFAIK.

Comment: and that only works if the output from the script is going to a tty, and not redirected somewhere else... also the comsub will eat tailing newlines, making an output that contains just empty lines seem like there was no output

Comment: Thanks, it would work in my case but I feel this is too much compared to just using grep, even if that's not grep's primary purpose.